# Grant employees rights to manage a Facebook page without using their personal account

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

At some point in the past, the best way we were aware of to allow employees to manage a client's Facebook business page was that we could ask the employee to add their work email address to their personal Facebook account and then the client could grant access by knowing the employee's work email address.  Some drawbacks of this is that it still involved their personal Facebook account which ideally we wouldn't be asking people to have to do, and also there's the issue of reassigning permissions upon turnover.

Is this still the best way to approach this situation?  Is there a better way wherein we don't have to ask an employee to use their own personal Facebook account, and also preferably where no permissions need to be reassigned if an employee's no longer with the company?

I understand that just because their personal account is used, doesn't mean that anyone viewing the page will see their personal account if the settings are done correctly - it's just that some employees feel uncomfortable using it, and there's a general business practice of not asking people to use their personal stuff.

The goal is to completely stay in compliance with the terms of service and not to do things that violate that, even if Facebook isn't catching/enforcing such violations.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you should try using the Business Manager straight from Facebook.  Simply have an administrator setup your business from [business.facebook.com](http://business.facebook.com). Once you have the base setup you can add additional administrators or employees using just their email address - in this case you can use their business email.  This will allow them to login without needing to use their personal accounts.

[image]

Comment: In 2021, this is not working: the invite link you get redirects you to a facebook login/signup form :(

Answer (score 1):

Business Manager isn't much of a solution. Employees still expose their personal accounts to their employers to use this.

The other problem with Business Manager is that it's hard to put pages in it. It's supposed to send requests to page admins for authorization, but those requests actually showing up is pretty 50/50. There are other massively annoying problems with Business Manager.

In the past, one could simply set up a personal Facebook account for a business and make it an admin on business pages. Then you could share the login credentials to the personal business account with authorized employees. Employees' personal accounts could then stay 100% personal. Unfortunately, Facebook is shutting this down. First by demanding your personal cell phone number if you want to be able to post on a business page. Then by employing algorithms designed to detect and shut down this technique.

The short answer is, no. If you want your business on Facebook, Facebook demands and requires that your employees both expose their personal Facebook accounts to their employers and co-workers and that your employees turn over their personal cell phone numbers to Facebook (who has a history of misusing those numbers).